# Determine best op-amp order for PCB design

Tags: analog, pcb-design

In my current design, I use 3 op-amps from a quad package (DIL 14). One is not used. For the design, it doesn't matter which op-amp is used when, since they should be identical.

For example, I'm currently using the amp 1 first, amp 3 second and amp 2 third because this was easier on breadboard. However, it may well be possible that on PCB it's more convenient to use amp 3 first, amp 4 second and amp 1 last.

Now I want to make a PCB out of it. How can I see or calculate which op-amp can be used in which stage for the best (when in doubt, shortest total wire length) PCB lay-out? Drawing all of them would take 4! = 24 drawings. I'm looking for a more efficient method.

Comment: It depends too heavily on the way you lay out the rest of your signal chain on the PCB for any algorithm to give you a "right" answer.  In any case, unless you're a masochist that likes to put audio traces under SMPS inductors with no ground plane, it's unlikely that an extra 3mm of track length here and there will be an issue.

Comment: Maybe you can show your circuit and give the exact opamp name if you'd like some help. Futhermore, as markt already said. A small difference in trace length doesn't realy matter, unless you work with high frequencies.

Comment: Placement is an inexact art, which is why computers are so pitiful at it. I think you just have to jumble the parts around (mentally, and on the screen) and see where they fit best, then reflect that back to your schematic. Kind of a puzzle.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany : +1. Best introduction to placement : http://planarity.net/

Comment: So there's no methodology to it, just try and find out what works best? I'm not concerned about a couple of mm, but I've seen lines making way too long connections where a small deviation solved the problem. I want a methodology to find those problems if possible.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Ooh that looks too addictive.

Comment: @Mast : there are some methodologies but covering them comprehensively is too broad. One example : high impedance nodes or virtual earth inputs are good receivers for EMI, so they should be kept as small as possible, even at the expense of longer traces elsewhere. But Spehro covered the gist of it.

Comment: Also not routing high-amplitude output signals near high-impedance input nodes is probably more important than track length.

Comment: In fact, what you do with the fourth unused op amp might be as important as how you handle the first three, depending on your circuit.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Of course, all unused inputs are grounded. However, since all components are through hole, reaching ground is not a problem (entire backplane is ground). Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: @Mast Not enough to ground the inputs.  Best practice is to use it as a follower, with the input between the rails.  An open loop op amp can hammer between the rails.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Good idea, I've modified the design to do just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concluded from the comments it's very situational. The best methodology in general is trial-and-error, only when working with RF or EMC sensitive boards a different approach is more suitable. Trace length is just about irrelevant.